# Conditional function based on either a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$('#fastbill').click(function(){
    if ($('#changevaluebill').attr('checked','true')){
        $('#changevaluebill').attr("value","Recharge Now");
    }
    else {
        $('#changevaluebill').attr("value","Proceed");
    }
});
```

The checkbox condition is not working.

Comment: `$('#changevaluebill').val(function () {
            return this.checked ? 'Recharge Now' : 'Proceed'
        });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to check if either a checkbox is checked

You can use `is(':checked')`

Try:

```
$('#fastbill').click(function(){
  if($('#changevaluebill').is(':checked')){
     $('#changevaluebill').val("Recharge Now");
  } else {
     $('#changevaluebill').val("Proceed");
  }
});
```

Other ways could be:

`$('#changevaluebill').prop('checked')`  // Boolean
`$('#changevaluebill:checked').length`  // Integer >0
`$('#changevaluebill:checked').size()` // .size() can be used instead of .length
`$('#changevaluebill').get(0).checked` // Boolean true
`$('#changevaluebill')[0].checked`      // Boolean true (same as above)

[Reference](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.gr/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
$('#changevaluebill').attr('checked','true')
```

That doesn't determine *if* the value it `'true'`, it *sets* the value to `'true'`.  You can use [the `.is()` function](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to conditionally check an aspect of the element.  Something like this:

```
$('#changevaluebill').is(':checked')
```

Comment: @muqeemkhan: Can you be more specific?  When you debug this in the browser, where and how specifically does it fail?  Is the code invoked at all?  Do the jQuery selectors find the elements you expect?  How does the logic progress?

Answer (score 1):

As others has said, you need to can use `.is()` and `:checked`.

But you should use .val() to set the value of an input field

```
$('#fastbill').click(function () {
    $('#changevaluebill').val(function () {
        return this.checked ? 'Recharge Now' : 'Proceed'
    });
});
```